# Using zend developer tool to create modules in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zftool2

i installed Zf using

`composer require zendframework/zftool:dev-master`

But whenever i try to run:

`zf.php create module <name>`

it shows the file content in the terminal.

How do i get this working?

Comment: Run "php zf.php create module <name>"